# How should I make two integers out of an int64 with bitwise operations in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

My solution would be:

```
IntLo := Integer(Value and $FFFFFFFF);
IntHi := Integer((Value shr 32) and $FFFFFFFF);
```

But I'm not sure this is the fastest solution.

*Edit:
I realised that there is no need for and-ing:

```
IntLo := Integer(Value);
IntHi := Integer(Value shr 32);
```

Comment: It's fast enough. But I think `IntLo := Int64Rec(X).Lo; IntHi := Int64Rec(X).Hi` is neater (but of type `Cardinal`).

Comment: How will you handle negative numbers?

Comment: @LURD In fact I should cast to cardinals because the WinAPI functions that I call need that. It's up to them to handle them as a signed 64-bit integer.